# Postgresql working with geographic coordinates?

Tags: postgresql

How to work with geographic coordinates in postgres, is there a standard alternative Postgis out of the box?

Comment: Postgres has `points` built in https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/datatype-geometric.html#id-1.5.7.16.5 if you don't want to use PostGIS.

Comment: What's wrong with PostGIS?

Answer (score 1):

Simply put,  NO there is not "standard" alternative.

GIS is a very deep subject.  Like, Do you need to provide for different types of map projections?  PostGIS is a standard that other are measures by.

I recommend you google why-should-you-care-about-postgis a gentle-introduction-to-spatial-databases